# Count the number of "columns" in an array (php)

Tags: php, json, count

I have the following JSON:

```
[ 
   { 
      "0":"2019-08-31",
      "1":"Bank Exp.",
      "2":"AED",
      "3":"30",
      "4":"",
      "5":"BANK FEE 10"
   },

   { 
      "0":"2019-08-31",
      "1":"Inventory",
      "2":"AED",
      "3":"122",
      "4":"",
      "5":"DEPOSIT 10000"
   },

   { 
      "0":"2019-08-31",
      "1":"Petty Cash",
      "2":"AED",
      "3":"4999",
      "4":"",
      "5":"DEPOSIT 10000"
   }
]
```

I am trying to Count the number of elements or columns in the Json. The result should be 6.
I have tried with echo count($data_array); (or sizeof) result is 3 (number of rows). How can I count the "columns" in this Json, taking into account that I must set as number of column  the Max number of column a specific row has?
Do I have to use a loop to count or can I do it with a single instruction?

Comment: Totally right. 6 not 5.Duly corrected thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that some var $json contains the JSON code you have above, you should be aware that the following code will result in an array of [objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) of type **stdClass**:

```php
$data_array = json_decode($json);
```

So $data_array is in fact an array, but it contains objects. As you pointed out, this will return the number of *rows* in your JSON:

```php
echo sizeof($data_array);
```

Clearly, the number of columns is not the number of rows. If you want to know the number of *columns* then you'll need to check one or more rows/objects/elements of your `$data_array` var. It's expedient to just look at the first element:

```
$col_count = sizeof($data_array[0]);
```

HOWEVER, this is going to cause an E_WARNING if $data_array's elements are objects of type stdClass:

```
PHP Warning:  sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /tmp/foo.php on line 33
```

You could optionally use the second parameter of the [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) function which will force PHP to decode every curly bracketed *object* in your JSON code as an associative array instead of stdClass objects:

```php
$data_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$col_count = sizeof($data_array[0]);
```

This yields a `$col_count` value of`6` which is the correct *for the first object in your array.* You should consider that later elements in $data_array may have either more or fewer columns, depending on the structure of your data. If you are sure that all elements will have the same number of columns, this is adequate, but if you have messy data, you may need to check *every element of your data array* to see what the true number of columns is:

```php
$data_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$col_count = 0;
foreach($data_array as $row) {
        $col_count = max($col_count, sizeof($row));
}
var_dump($col_count);
```

This will yield a `$col_count` value which reflects the *maximum* number of columns encountered in any element of your JSON. Clearly, there may be performance considerations if your JSON contains a large number of elements. It all depends on your JSON data and the nature of your application.

EDIT:
Instead of an explicit foreach loop, I think you can get away with this, but it will still require PHP to loop through your data structure. That said, it'll probably be faster:

```php
$max_col_count = max(array_map("count", $data_array));
```

Comment: $max_col_count = max(array_map("count", $data_array)); works beautifully. Congrats and thanks for the detailed and precise answer!

Comment: My pleasure! Thank you for your courteous response and for your upvotes. 

Answer (score 2):

`count($data_array)` counts the number of elements in an array. In your case, is 3. But your array is multidimensional (matrix). So you need to count on some index to get the number of columns on that position:

```
<?php
echo count($data_array[0]);
```